# Assembler. Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Tags: ассемблер, стек

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить задачу! Вижу Ассемблер первый раз. Использую его как вставку. Мне нужно массив отсортировать в обратном порядке. Думал использовать стек. Вот код:

```
int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr=new int[n];
    cout << "MAS 1: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    __asm
    {
        mov ECX, n
        xor ESI, ESI
        first_point:
        mov EAX, arr[ESI]
        push EAX
            add ESI, 1
            loop first_point
            mov ECX, n
            xor ESI, ESI
        second_point:
        pop EAX
            mov arr[ESI], EAX
            add ESI, 1
            loop second_point
    }
    cout << "MAS 2: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
```

Но проблема в том, что здесь `mov EAX, arr[ESI]` в `EAX` не то число, которое в массиве, а просто набор цифр. Как решить это? И извините за беспокойство!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А такой синтаксис допускается во вставках `mov EAX, arr[ESI]`? Впрочем, оно всё равно не так обрабатывается, как задумывалось.

Можно сделать так: (подразумевая размер int 4)

```
mov edx, arr

...
mov eax, [edx + esi * 4]
```

Кроме того, убедитесь, что регистр ESI можно портить во вставке. Обычно его полагается сохранять и восстанавливать.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сделал как вы сказали и все получилось.